# HTC Desire S not listed on HTC support website?

Tags: htc-desire-s

I should be getting a HTC Desire S android phone in the next few days. It is listed on the HTC website at http://www.htc.com/uk/product/desires/overview.html, but doesn't appear on the HTC support site at http://www.htc.com/uk/support.aspx.

Does anyone know why this this is, or how I can get to the support page for this phone? I'd like to have a look at the Users Guide before the phone arrives.

Comment: It's listed there now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [manual from the International site](http://www.htc.com/www/userguide.aspx?p_id=391)?